# New review system

Tags: discussion

The system of reviewing posts on SE sites has been improved some time ago. Now the review tasks are compiled in stacks and shown one review post at a time. All possible actions that you can perform with the post are shown in the top right corner.

**Every user with 1000 reputation may review posts!** There are so far 7 such users in our community (and yet more to come!). **Let's go and try the new review system out.**

Click on the review field in the upper left corner of the screen:

[image: The review field]

and get started!

Answer (score 1):

As we got a large inflow of new users, the need to reviewing posts has increased dramatically.  I'm doing my best to keep up with them, but there are limits on how many posts one user can review in each of the categories.  A couple of times (including today) I exhausted my quota in the categories that have a large number of posts.

We do have a few folks with sufficient rep to do the review.  There aren't that many posts to be reviewed and it doesn't take too much time, so let's try to spare 10-15 minutes a day on the reviews.

Comment: Thank you, Aleks G! I'm often looking on the top recent questions instead of using the review system, so some of the posts may still be marked for review but they may not need it anymore. I'll try to stick to the review system in the future.

Comment: @Olga thank you.  I do see that quite a few posts that are showing in the review system already have comments by yourself or shabunc, therefore if we do it via the review system, we'll be keeping the tabs on that one as well.

Comment: @Olga, I believe that if you already edited or commented on the post that is in the review queue while outside of it, once you check the queue you already have an option to press “I’m done” to complete the review.

Comment: @theUg Yes, now it is possible, The system tracks one's actions irrespective of whether they are performed within the review window or not.